# Aligning two input fields side by side

Tags: php, html, css, class

I know this is a very stupid question but I've tried everything (div wrappers, floating div, p classes) and couldn't figure it out. I simply want to align the "isim & soyisim" fields on the second column side by side (these are name & surname fields). There's a problem with my code but I cannot find it, and it's driving me insane. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. See it here:

http://www.wondercatspopup.com/hesabim/

The code is as follows:

```
     <p class="form-row form-row-first">
          <label style="display:none!important;" for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <span class="required">
             *
            </span>
          </label>

          <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text placeholder" placeholder="İsim *" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    
         <label style="display:none!important;" for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text placeholder" placeholder="Soyisim *" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
       
      </p>

      <p class="form-row form-row-wide">

          <label style="display:none!important;" for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
          <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text placeholder" placeholder="Telefon *" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
      </p>

       <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Add your code to the issue. This means that if someone finds this question in 5 years after your site is gone they can still see the issue.

Comment: just added it. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text box is using full width of screen.

try setting specific width to your text-boxes with display: inline-block property.

Example:
HTML

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" />
</div>
```

STYLE

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Another approach: You may also use "display : flex" style to div box

Comment: Glad it worked. Then can you please accept my answer.

Comment: Hello again, it works fine on desktop but on mobile it'a aligned weirdly when placed in the footer. (please see the link above) Can you perhaps help me with that one as well?

Comment: For mobile, each device got different screen sizes, so if you set hardcoded value (i.e. 150px), it'll not align properly. Either use @media queries to specific width/height based on screen width else use fluid design (i.e. percentage like width: 30%)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a width to the `input box`. Then I will work fine.```

```
input[type="text"] { //or your class 
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
margin-right:20px; // to set some margin in the right
}
```